# Is there a word for event-based like spatial is for space?

Tags: single-word-requests

Time → temporal

Space →  spatial

Event →  ?

Specifically, I would like a word that works in this context:

> Proust was invoked by the event of smelling cookies to pen his
>   masterpiece *In Search of Lost Time*. Hence his inspiration was ______ .

I am looking for that one word which would indicate it was an event-based trigger.

Comment: 'Eventual' is not obsolete in the sense 'of the nature of an event or result'.

Comment: Depending on context, "occurrent" might fit the bill...

Comment: I would use 'situational'

Comment: I was hesitant to use situational after looking at the definition: "a set of circumstances in which one finds oneself; a state of affairs". That meant more a state to me, as opposed to an event. You could always argue that there is a state of 'event/s occurring' of course... But yeah, hrrrrm  ...  oh, and I don't mean to suggest my answer(s) didn't also have their own imprecision!  :)

Comment: The problem is that events are discrete, vs occurring on a continuum like time and space.  Terminology that works in a continuous domain may not work in a disjointed domain.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the what definition of 'event' you had in mind.

But try:

**[Phenomenal](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/phenomenal)**

> Perceptible by the senses or through immediate experience: *the
> phenomenal world*

Among others:

Experiential

Factual

Incidental

Answer (score 0):

[Event-driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven):  refers to a methodology that focuses on events and event dependencies.