# Is there a word for depth-based like spatial is for space?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to describe types of trends that we see in my research of a lake. I am doing a study that combines spatial (across the lake) and depth-discrete samples (multiple depths in the lake). I would like to distinguish between the two:

> I will look for spatial and _____ trends in the lake.

- Space --> spatial
- Time --> temporal
- Depth --> ???

I want to use "deptual" but unfortunately that is not a word...

Thank you to this post for getting close to the question I'm trying to ask:
[Is there a word for event-based like spatial is for space?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/276314/is-there-a-word-for-event-based-like-spatial-is-for-space)

Comment: Depth in what sense? Can you give the sentence where you would use this word?

Comment: @Laurel Yes, my first thought was that it was to do with ocean depth or the depth of a mine or well. But I quickly realised that those measurements are spatial.

Comment: Hi @Laurel. I do mean physical depth of a lake, actually. I am doing a study that combines spatial (across the lake) and depth-discrete samples (multiple depths in the lake). I would like to distinguish between the two. My example sentence is: "I will look for spatial and _____ trends in the lake."

Answer (score 1):

You might find suitable the following construction by means of the suffix "-wise"; it yields several well established terms, but is as well endowed with the characteristic of being freely productive.

> **-wise** (*Shorter OED*) Forming ***a)*** advs. and adjs. chiefly from ns. w the sense '(that is) in the manner, form or direction of' as *crosswise, latticewise, otherwise*, **b)** advs. from ns. w the sense 'as regards, in terms of' as *pairwise, plotwise*'now freely productive in the formation of nonce-words  as *employment-wise, moneywise, publicity-wise*, etc.).

- depthwise

You dispose [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22depthwise%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) of 111 examples to get a feel of this word, which is in fact an existant, freely produced word (that is, not in the dictionaries (yet)).